# What is the best way to store different type of objects in one data structure scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have different types of trait Pipe objects and I want to store these objects in one structure for further accessing.pipeline order changes dynamically.

```
trait Pipe[In, Out] {

  def apply(rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out]

  def |[Final](next: Pipe[Out, Final]): Pipe[In, Final] = {
    // Close over outer object
    val self = this
    new Pipe[In, Final] {
      // Run first transform, pass results to next
      def apply(rdd: RDD[In]) = next(self(rdd))
    }
  }

}
val timestampConverter = new Pipe[String, String]
val summaryBuilder = new Pipe[String, String]
val rddSeperator = new Pipe[String, (String, ArrayBuffer[Double])]
val rddSorter = new Pipe[(String, Double), String]

val pipeline = timestampConverter | summaryBuilder | rddSeperator | rddSorter
```

Comment: Can you say more precisely what you want to do with the Pipe objects? Can you give an example? Is the question really related to spark?

Answer (score 0):

```
  import shapeless.hlist.ops._
  import shapless.::

  trait Pipe[In, HL <: HList] { self =>

    def apply(rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out]

    def |[Final](
      next: Pipe[Out, Final :: HL]
    ): Pipe[In, Final :: HL] = {

      new Pipe[In, Final :: HL] {
        // Run first transform, pass results to next
        def apply(rdd: RDD[In]) = next(self(rdd))
      }
    }  
  }
```

Sounds like you could do with a simple heterogenous list. I'm not sure how well this plays with Spark because of serializations, but worth a shot. Then you can reverse `HL` to get the arguments in input order.

The `self` reference is not necessary, this isn't JavaScript.